# How to handle multiple controlled inputs with react es6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Here's my fiddle

https://codepen.io/seunlanlege/pen/XjvgPJ?editors=0011

I have two inputs and I'm trying to use one method to handle the `onChange` event for any input field.

I've torn the internet apart looking for a solution but came up with nothing.

I'm using es6 please how do I go about this?

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  `constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text:{
      e:'hi',
      c:''
    }};
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }`

  `handleChange(event,property) {
    const text = this.state.text;
      text[property] = event.target.value;
      this.setState({text});
  }`

  `handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('Text field value is: ' + this.state.text.e);
  }`

  `render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.text.e}</div>
        <input type="text"
          placeholder="Hello!"
          value={this.state.text.e}
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
        <input type="text"
          placeholder="Hello!"
          value={this.state.text.c}
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}`

ReactDOM.render(
  `<Form />`,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Please put your code in the question, using the snippet tool. Links go stale fast...

Comment: i can't, i keep getting formatting error.

Comment: Y̶o̶u̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶t̶i̶d̶y̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶t̶o̶n̶.̶  - Should you be returning HTML without putting it in a string? That sounds wrong to me

Comment: it's not working, can you please look at the pen and tell me what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not passed the propert to the handeChange function. pass it like `this.handleChange.bind(this, 'e')` and also the order of receiving props is wrong, property will be the first argument and then the event and not the reverse.

Code:

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text:{
      e:'hi',
      c:''
    }};
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(property, event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    const text = {...this.state.text};
      text[property] = event.target.value;
      this.setState({ text }); //or you can use the shorthand here. ES6 is awesome <3
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('Text field value is: ' + this.state.text.e);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.text.e}</div>
        <div>{this.state.text.c}</div>
        <input type="text"
          placeholder="Hello!"
          value={this.state.text.e}
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'e')} />
        <input type="text"
          placeholder="Hello!"
          value={this.state.text.c}
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'c')} />
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Form />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ameyPE?editors=0011)**

Comment: thanks alot, you just saved me from writing on change functions for every input field i have

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to give each of your inputs a `name` attribute and set the state based on that:

```js
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: {
      e: 'hi',
      c: ''
    } };
    this.onChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    var oldState = this.state.text;
    var newState = { [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
    
    // I have to assign/join because you've put the text state in a parent object.
    this.setState({ text: Object.assign(oldState, newState) });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('Text field value is: ' + this.state.text.e);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.text.e}</div>
        <input type="text"
          placeholder="Hello!"
          name="e"
          value={this.state.text.e}
          onChange={this.onChange} />
        <input type="text"
          placeholder="Hello!"
          name="c"
          value={this.state.text.c}
          onChange={this.onChange} />
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Form />,
  document.getElementById('View')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="View"></div>
```

Also, there are so-called [two-way binding helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html). As I understand they still show mixins in React's documentation, so you are probably better off with third party libraries like [`react-link-state`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-link-state):

```
this.state = {
  username: '',
  password: '',
  toggle: false
};

<input type="text" valueLink={linkState(this, 'username')} />
<input type="password" valueLink={linkState(this, 'password')} />
<input type="checkbox" checkedLink={linkState(this, 'toggle')} />
```