# React - handle multiple toggle buttons (input type radio) with one function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got my custom icon toggle component:

```
class ToggleIconSwitch extends Component {

  render() {
    const { leftIcon, rightIcon, name, handleOptionChange, checked, leftValue, rightValue } = this.props

    return (
      <div className="toggle-switch-icon-wrapper">
        <div className="toggle-switch">
          <input 
            type="radio" 
            name={ name } 
            id={ leftValue } 
            value={ leftValue } 
            checked={ checked === leftValue } 
            onChange={ handleOptionChange }
          />
          <label htmlFor={ leftValue } className="icon">{ leftIcon }</label>
          <input 
            type="radio" 
            name={ name } 
            id={ rightValue } 
            value={ rightValue } 
            checked={ checked === rightValue } 
            onChange={ handleOptionChange }
          />
          <label htmlFor={ rightValue } className="icon">{ rightIcon }</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and then I've got multiple toggles on some page and I want to handle each toggle input change...

```
_.map(acl, (permission) => {
  return (
    <div className="row" key={ permission.id } >
      <ToggleIconSwitch
        name={ _.toString(permission.id) }
        leftIcon={ <VisibilityIcon className="svg" /> }
        leftValue="read"
        rightIcon={ <CreateIcon className="svg"/> }
        rightValue="write"
        checked={ permission.permission }
        handleOptionChange={ this.toggleUsersPermission }
      />
      <IconButton 
        aria-label="Delete" 
        className="icon-button animate"
        onClick={ this.openDeleteDialog(permission) }
      >
        <CloseIcon className="icon-button-red" />
      </IconButton>
    </div>
  )
})
```

The problem is that the `toggleUsersPermission` function is always called only for the first `ToggleIconSwitch` component, even if I click on another `ToggleIconSwitch`. It also does not react when I click on the other toggle component's label, which is `checked` in first toggle component in list. I'm always getting `event.target` of the first toggle in list ... Why?

Try to click on the icons in CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/olyr8vmox9)

Comment: Are the `permission.id` values unique?

The `key` property needs to be unique for each sibling element dynamically created like this. Otherwise React gets all confused.

Comment: I think [this prior Stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358017/how-to-handle-multiple-controlled-inputs-with-react-es6) might help. Talks about context binding. Alternatively, you could pass in the ID of the individual toggle component to `toggleUsersPermission` and then have that return a handle function which "knows" which element to work with.

Comment: @DylanPierce yes, permission.id values are unique
@uncleoptimus it doesn't work, I tried to pass `this.toggleUsersPermission.bind(this, permission.id)` as `handleOptionChange` function, but it's same as before, it doesn't handle any toggle clicks but first, and on the other toggles it handles clicking on the unchecked value (of first toggle), but it always returns `permission.id` of the first toggle

Comment: @uncleoptimus try my example in CodeSandbox which I provided today ... if you click on the icons in second toggle (it's not styled now), you'll see that radio buttons in fthe first toggle are blinking (dispatching event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in labels, they have all equal `htmlFor` value and also input ids were same